# Java Process Input Stream Blank on Linux

Tags: java, linux, process

When I open a linux terminal and run

```
/usr/sbin/lsof -t TestJar.jar
```

I get the correct PID returned as expected. However, when I execute the same statement through java (below) I get nothing returned.

```
try {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", "/usr/sbin/lsof -t TestJar.jar");
        Process process = builder.start();
        System.out.println("----------------");
        //Thread.sleep(3000);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while(line != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        
        process.destroy();
        reader.close();
        System.out.println("----------------");
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("FAILED");
        Main.printToErrorLog(e);
    }
```

I've even printed out the exact command to the console and copy and pasted it to the terminal. Any ideas on what I'm overlooking?

Comment: When you change the command in `ProcessBuilder` to `"/usr/sbin/lsof -t TestJar.jar > /tmp/output.txt"`, does the file `/tmp/output.txt` contain the expected output? Does your Java program get the output when you replace the command with e.g. `"echo 123"`?

Comment: You shouldn't have call to destroy(). Check the exit code of the process (waitFor) and  what is on standard error (or redirectErrorStream(true)), then edit question when you know. Most likely bash is not on Java's path.

Comment: 1.  There is no need for bash here.  Just write `new ProcessBuilder("/usr/sbin/lsof", "-t", "TestJar.jar")`.  2.  You are suppressing the standard error of lsof.  Remove your while-loop entirely, remove the BufferedReader, and call `builder.inheritIO()`.  That method will propagate both the standard output and standard error of the child process to your Java program, allowing you to see everything that process prints.

Comment: Try `ProcessHandle.allProcesses().filter(p ->p.info().commandLine().orElse("").contains("TestJar.jar")).forEach(p ->p.destroy());` A whole lot easier and X-platform too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your JVM has a different working directory to the terminal, and the command `/usr/sbin/lsof -t TestJar.jar` will only work from the current directory of `TestJar.jar` because otherwise `lsof` has no idea which filesystem path you are referring to. You don't handle STDERR so you have lost the error message which probably starts with:

```
lsof: status error on TestJar.jar: No such file or directory
```

The easiest way to see STDERR is to follow @VGR suggestion adding `builder.inheritIO();` or as I suggested in comments `builder.redirectErrorStream(true);`. You can fix the issue by passing in the absolute path to TestJar.jar or by using `builder.directory(new File("/abs/path/tothejar"))` to change directory to the right place before starting `lsof`.

You don't need to run bash here either, try calling directly using the [start method of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75843148/runtime-exec-freezes-on-execution-of-ffmpeg-audio-replacing-command-that-works/75843278#75843278):

```
// Some systems have need this path instead: /usr/bin/lsof
start(new String[]{"/usr/sbin/lsof", "-t", "/abs/path/tothejar/TestJar.jar"}, null, System.out, null);
```

Comment: By the way see @g00se comment for Java ProcessHandle code if you are simply looking up instances of your app, whereas you need `lsof` if you want to lookup all PID that are currently accessing `TestJar.jar`